# Odoo: Access field by it's name (given as string)

Tags: odoo

I have a model, where I want to access a field, given by a string. Example:

```
def test(self):
    field = 'name'
    name = getattr(self, field)
```

This works fine - name is set to self.name. But then I want to access a related field:

```
def test2(self):
    field = 'partner_id.name'
    name = getattr(self, field)
```

That doesn't work (because 'partner_id.name' does not exist on self). Any idea how to do it right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getattr` doesn't support the dot notation, only simple attribute names. You can however create a simple function that does:

```
def getfield(model, field_name):
    value = model
    for part in field_name.split('.'):
        value = getattr(value, part)
    return value
```

You would use it like this:

```
def test2(self):
    field = 'partner_id.name'
    name = getfield(self, field)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `object` that contain `partner_id.name`

```
def test2(self):
    field = 'name'
    object = self.pool.get('res.partner').browse(cr, uid, self.partner_id.id)#v7
    #object = self.env['res.partner'].browse(self.partner_id.id)#v8
    name = getattr(object, field)
```

Answer (score 0):

I also came across another solution, inspired by the mail template system:

```
from openerp.tools.safe_eval import safe_eval as eval

def test2(self):
    field = 'partner_id.name'
    field = 'object.' + field
    name = eval(field, {'object': self})
```

Comment: Note that this may have a severe security implication if `field` is a user provided value. In general extreme caution is required when using `eval`.